# How to delete an object from a ListView using a button in the ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: User interface]

Write a text in the `inputTitle` `TextBox` and press the *Add* button to add item to the `TaskList` `ListView`.

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new AddItem();
        newItems = new ObservableCollection<AddItem> { };
        taskList.ItemsSource = newItems;

    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newItem = new AddItem()
        {
            Title = inputTitle.Text,
        };

        newItems.Add(newItem);
        taskList.SelectedItem = newItem;
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

It is to add item to `TaskList` by pressing the *Add* button, and I want to delete it by pressing *Del* button.

```
<Canvas Margin="0,0,0,10">
    <Canvas Height="81" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="17" Width="380">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="TaskTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="24" Width="380" FontSize="20" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="inputTitle" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="320" FontSize="24" Canvas.Top="27" Height="44" TabIndex="1" Canvas.Left="4" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
        <Button x:Name="addButton" Content="Add" Canvas.Left="333" Canvas.Top="32" Height="34" Width="34" Click="addButton_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding CanAdd, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Canvas>
    <ListView x:Name="taskList" Height="500" Width="400" Canvas.Top="116">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox >
                        <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2.5" ScaleY="2.5"/>
                        </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                    </CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" Width="290"/>
                    <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="Del" Height="34" Width="34" Click="deleteButton_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Can you show your XAML, where you define the `Del` buttons?

Comment: <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="Del" Height="34" Width="34" Click="deleteButton_Click"/>
As the item increases, button increases as well.

Comment: Can you show your `ListBox` definition?

Comment: added  XAML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netcore-3.1) property of `Button` to the current item.

```
<ListView x:Name="taskList" Height="500" Width="400" Canvas.Top="116" ItemsSource="{Binding newItems}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox >
               <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2.5" ScaleY="2.5"/>
               </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" Width="290"/>
            <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="Del" Height="34" Width="34" Click="deleteButton_Click" Tag="{Binding}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As you bind the `Tag` property to your current item, you can use that to remove it from the collection.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClickDel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var button = (Button)sender;
var item = (AddItem)button.Tag;

newItems.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: @김규태 I have adapted the code to the `ListView` sample that you posted.